# (Excel/VBA) Change the number in a text box every time a page prints using a range of cells

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, printing

I am printing parking placards. I need a way to have the member number on the placard change every time a page prints. I want to input the member numbers into cells A2 through A8 of sheet2 for example.

I used some other guides and I'm pretty sure I botched it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub PrintCopies()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim VList As Variant

    VList = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A4").Value
    For i = LBound(VList) To UBound(VList)
        Sheets(Sheet1).Shapes("Number").TextFrame.Characters.Text = VList(i)
        ActiveSheet.PrintOut
    Next
End Sub
```

Picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aozEb.jpg

Comment: It is a 2D array `VList(i,1)`

Comment: Only the row number would change not the column. So I guess VList(A, i)

Comment: @RyanGoldberg - it's row first, then column. See [Arrays and Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx).

Comment: Understood, yes it's a 2D array.

Comment: `Sheets(Sheet1).Shapes("Number").TextFrame.Characters.Text = VList(i,1)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout I am going to post a picture to try and help explain what I'm looking to do.

Comment: Sure. BTW `Sheets(Sheet1)` should be `Sheets("Sheet1")` A typo I guess?

Comment: So in those pictures, the "0000" is where I would like the numbers from Sheet2 to go. I want to run the VBA code and have it auto-populate on each iteration. Currently, when I run the script I get "Runtime error 9, Script out of range".

Comment: @SiddharthRout Actually, I just ran it with the edit you made and it ran perfectly. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: So is it sorted?

Comment: Yes, everything is working, thank you.

Comment: BTW if the codename of the worksheet is also `Sheet1` then your code can also be written as `Sheet1.Shapes("Number").TextFrame.Characters.Text = VList(i,1)` ;)